# Previously Triggered Recursive Function Doesn't See New Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that takes text and renders it to the DOM character by character to create a typewriter effect. To accomplish this, the function keeps calling itself over and over again for each character.

Sometimes I want to jump to another level and so my `props.chapter` changes and my `textArray` gets updated. However the function that was invoked before the props and textArray changed still sees the old values with each successive time it calls itself.

If I trigger the function a second time after the prop changes, the two invokations run simultaneously with one display the old data and one display the new data.

I am using React with Hooks.

Here is my function:

```
const typewriter = () => {
            console.log(props.chapter); //will always show the props at invokation
            sContents = [''];
            iRow = Math.max(0, iIndex - iScrollAt);
            while (iRow < iIndex) {
                sContents[iIndex] += textArray[iRow++];
                sContents[iIndex] = '';
            }

            //This is the text I render to the DOM later
            setText((text) => {
                text[iIndex] = <p key={`line-${iIndex}`}>{sContents[iIndex] + textArray[iIndex].substring(0, iTextPos)}<span className='caret'></span></p>;
                return [...text];
            }); 

            if (iTextPos++ == iArrLength) {
                iTextPos = 0;
                iIndex++;
                if (iIndex != textArray.length) {
                    setSFXon(false);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        //Clear carat from previous line
                        setText((text) => {
                            if(text[iIndex -1]){
                                text[iIndex-1] = <p key={`line-${iIndex-1}`}>{sContents[iIndex-1] + textArray[iIndex-1].substring(0, iArrLength)}</p>;
                            }
                            text[iIndex] = <p key={`line-${iIndex}`}><span className='caret'></span></p>
                            return [...text];
                        });
                        //Write next line
                        iArrLength = textArray[iIndex].length; //Next line's length
                       //==================
                       //RECURSIVE CALL HERE
                       //==================
                        typewriter()
                    }, 1500);
                }else{
                    //Make last line carat blink
                    setText((text) => {
                        text[iIndex-1] = <p key={`line-${iIndex-1}`}>{sContents[iIndex-1] + textArray[iIndex-1].substring(0, iArrLength)}<span className='caret blink'></span></p>;
                        return [...text];
                    });
                }
            } else {
                //==================
                // RECURSIVE CALL HERE
                //==================
                setTimeout(() => typewriter(), iSpeed);
            }
    }
```

Comment: So did you do anything after `textArray` changed?

Comment: I call the function a second time, and then I see both the old `textArray` and new `textArray` being printed.

Comment: Can you post the whole component? Looks like it's related to some re-render issue.

Comment: I believe the issue is related to the fact that typerwriter calls itself so I think the nested instances of the function lose scope. I had to rewrite the functionality using setInterval instead so it wouldn't be recursive and that got the desired effect.